Can't create office location filter using PnP Webparts
I have created a filter by department in my company directory page. I did this by going into Entra ID and populating the department field for each user in my organization and then going into my SharePoint intranet and using the PnP Webparts and configuring the filter. When I do the same for Office Location, the property BaseOfficeLocation shows "null" in the PnP webparts and I am unable to filter by office location. I have checked in Entra ID and SharePoint admin center and the Office Location field is correctly filled out for every user. Can someone please help with this?
